# Sklearn trying to convert string list to floats

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to make a `sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel="linear")` algorithm work. My X is an array made with `[misc.imread(each).flatten() for each in filenames]` and my y2 is a part of a list made of strings such as `["A","1","4","F"..]`.

When I try to `clf.fit(X,y2)`, sklearn tries to convert my string list into floats and fails, throwing `ValueError: could not convert string to float`. How can I solve this?

EDIT: Upgrading sklearn to 0.15 solved the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a helper class in scikit-learn which implements this nicely, it's called `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
y2 = ["A","1","4","F","A","1","4","F"]
lb = LabelEncoder()
y = lb.fit_transform(y2)
# y is now: array([2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 3])
```

In order to get back to your original labels (e.g. after classifying unseen data using `SVC`), use the `inverse_transform` of `LabelEncoder` to restore the string labels:

```
lb.inverse_transform(y)
# => array(['A', '1', '4', 'F', 'A', '1', '4', 'F'], dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: The issue appears to be about the version of sklearn. It throws the error in 0.11 and LabelEncoder is not present in that version. Upgrading sklearn to 0.15 solved the problem without any code added.

Comment: Yes, 0.11 is quite dated, you need at least 0.12 if not 0.13 I guess, haven't verified it though...

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign a unique integer to each unique string label. I'm assuming your `y2` variable contains multiple instances of each class.

So maybe it looks more like:

```
y2 = ["A","1","4","F","A","1","4","F"]
```

Now you could do something like:

```
S = set(y2) # collect unique label names
D = dict( zip(S, range(len(S))) ) # assign each string an integer, and put it in a dict
Y = [D[y2_] for y2_ in y2] # store class labels as ints
```

For `y2` above, this yields:

```
>>> print Y
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Now it works. I was thinking about that, but I could not write this simple. Thanks for the help