# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'what' (Sklearn), How to use the labelencoder?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, decision-tree, sklearn-pandas

I have two training sets input and output set

```
X = df['First Word']

y = df['Answers']
```

When I tried:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)
predictions = model.predict(['how'])
```

I got the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'what'
```

The error refers to that str() cannot be passed to the fit() method.

How to use the LabelEncoder in this case so that the above code works?

Comment: This kind of error ValueError: could not convert string to float:  can occur when reading a dataframe from a csv file with types as df = df[['p']].astype({'p': float}). If the csv was recorded with empty spaces, python will not recognize the space character as a nan. You will need to overwrite empty cells with NaN with df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

Comment: there are no nans

Comment: please check this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016752/sklearn-trying-to-convert-string-list-to-floats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All ML models need input in the form of numbers so you need to encode the input data either label encoder or one-hot encoding as per your need.

you can encode your dataframe using the below code

```
 from sklearn import preprocessing
 le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
 X = le.fit_transform(X)
```

After encoding pass to model, I hope you won't get that error